# How can I accurately calculate the surface area from a binary picture in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have one image that's been divided into three parts [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rurw.png) , and i plan to find the surface area from each parts for further calculation.

I have tried to find its boundary using `cv2.findCountours` and `cv.2drawContours`, but when im using `cv2.contourArea` to calculate the surface area, the output value always showing 0,0.

for example this [part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu1aj.png) im using

```
cr_midfoot = cv2.imread('cr_midfoot.png')

m_edged = cv2.Canny(cr_midfoot, 30, 200)
m_edged.copy()
contours_m, hierarchy_m = cv2.findContours(m_edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cont_midfoot = cv2.drawContours(cr_midfoot, contours_m, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
midfoot_area = cv2.contourArea(contours_m[0])
cv2.imshow('contour midfoot', cont_midfoot)
print(midfoot_area)
```

but i couldnt find the information i needed, is there any way to do it? Im using OpenCV and Numpy.

Comment: Why not just count the white pixels?

Comment: im sorry im new to python, how can i count the white pixels?

Comment: You can very easily find answers to that by searching for e.g. _opencv count white pixels_

Comment: Draw a white filled contour on a black background. Then either get the contour area or use np.count_nonzero(). See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `np.sum()` on the desired image, which will give you the white area (because white is `1` and black is `0`). In case you need the black area - use the `cv2.bitwise_not(img)` and then sum it up.

```
cr_midfoot = cv2.imread('cr_midfoot.png')
cr_midfoot_gray= cv2.cvtColor(cr_midfoot , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
m_edged = cv2.Canny(cr_midfoot, 30, 200)
white_area  = np.sum(m_edged)
```

Cheers.